# How to extract certain string from a line of string using find.()

Tags: python, string, extract

```
file_name_to_preprocessing_method("heloc_dataset_v1(exc empty rows.).csv_pre(-1,asis).csv")
```

should return the string "(-1,asis)", possibly using `.find()`.

[image]

Comment: can you please make the body clearer

Comment: def file_name_to_preprocessing_method(s): execute certain string functions on s, assign the answer to the variable res, and finally return res

Comment: **We don't allow images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow.** Please post all text as ([formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)) text. Read more [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Questions with images of text/code/errors are subject to being closed.

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.findall` for a regex approach:

```py
inp = "file_name_to_preprocessing_method(\"heloc_dataset_v1(exc empty rows.).csv_pre(-1,asis).csv\")"
matches = re.findall(r'\bcsv_pre(\(.*?\))', inp)
print(matches[0])  # (-1,asis)
```